# Adding an item to a List with jQuery removes it right afterwards

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the code I have. When I try to add via the "Add"-Button, the item shows for a second in the list, but then gets removed.

I don't understand why.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submitButton").click(addListItem);
});

function addListItem() {
    var $entryText = $("#entry").val();
    $("#list").append("<li>" + $entryText + "</li>");
}
```

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle

Comment: I guess `#submitButton` is an input submit button. You need then to prevent default behaviour of submitting FORM because submitting a FORM refresh/redirect the page

Comment: You are missing a `$` before `('#submitButton').click(...`

Comment: @A.Wolff how can I change the button to a normal one instead?

Comment: @Algram What do you call normal button? The default type for button element is `submit` anyway. You should use instead: `function addListItem(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); ... }`

Comment: [This works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/aq3hLsa1/)

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes, I just changed the type to "button" and now it works, thank you very much!

Comment: @Algram Ya this is indeed an other/better solution ;) Better because you explicitely tell in HTML markup that this button isn't used for submitting FORM

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the code above, nothing looks suspicious. There might be something else going on with your code. I've set up a fiddle here with the code above working as intended: https://jsfiddle.net/3ruejjrv/

```
<ul id="list"><li>Test</li></ul>
<input type="text" id="entry" />
<input type="button" id="submitButton" value="addItem" />
```

Is your submit action submitting a form and refreshing a page?

Comment: Regarding OP comments, this is jsFiddle replicating issue: https://jsfiddle.net/3ruejjrv/1/

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be submitting the form when you click the button.

Adding a `e.preventDefault();` line seems to fix the problem as per this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3ruejjrv/2/